# How can I get the length of a string using TypeScript types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the length of a string as a number:

```
type Length = LengthOfString<"hello">
//   ^? should be 5
```

I'm not sure where to begin on this. How can I accomplish this?

(I'm trying to learn more about typescript's type system -- I am not applying this to JS code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a template literal string to split of each char of the string. We append some element to the tuple `L` for each char we can retrieve.

```
type LengthOfString<T extends string, L extends any[] = []> = 
  T extends `${string}${infer R}` 
    ? LengthOfString<R, [...L, string]>
    : L["length"]
```

When there are no more chars left, we return the `length` of `L`

Result:

```
type Length = LengthOfString<"hello">
//   ^? 5
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=8&ssc=10&pln=7&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAMlAdgcxACwPIDMDKIBOAligDwAqMUAHiEgCYDOMDBxyANPJTfUwIaIwAbQC6MALwxRAPgkxgMGBWq1EjGAAMAJAG8WRFAF9dxLFHwwASoY3zFigPzwkqTLlalLnIQDo-cTn02EWkFewAueCEAIgAbF3RokWBQSFgEFHQ5DNdsPANkEmi0KFjYgHto0IB6avsAPScAViA)

Comment: Great! By the way, I put the `^?` there because it's used as a label for types. See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBAMlAdgcxACwPIDMDKIBOAligDwAqMUAHiEgCYDOMDBxyANPJTfUwIaIwAbQC6MALwxRAPgkxgMGBWq1EjGAAMAJAG8WRFAF9dxLFHwwASoY3zFigPzwkqTLlalLnIQDo-cTn02EWkFewAueCEAIgAbF3RokWBQSFgEFHQ5DNdsPANkEmi0KFjYgHto0IB6avsAPQcgA)

Comment: @LeoDog896 - Ah of course. I always put the computed type there for the answer but forget to remove it in the playground :)