# In TypeScript's type system how can I check for freshness for typed parameters?

Tags: typescript

Building off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74445734/how-can-i-get-the-length-of-a-string-using-typescript-types) (no I do not have a grand scheme, I simply thought of this after getting my question answered.):

I have the following:

```
type LengthOfString<T extends string, L extends any[] = []> = 
  T extends `${string}${infer R}` 
    ? LengthOfString<R, [...L, string]>
    : L["length"]

type StringOfLength<T extends string, N extends number> = LengthOfString<T> extends N ? T : never

function isStringOfLength<T extends string, N extends number>(str: T, len: N): str is StringOfLength<T, N> {
  return str.length === len
}

function takeString<T extends string>(str: StringOfLength<T, 5>) {
  if (!isStringOfLength<T, 5>(str, 5)) throw Error("String length !== 5")
  console.log(str)
}

// Works! (fresh)
takeString("22222")

// As expected, errors (fresh)
takeString("2222")

let str = "22222"

// Errors -- how can I avoid this? (str isn't fresh)
takeString(str)
```

As shown in the code, I have a run-time type guard `isStringOfLength` that is meant to throw runtime errors for non-fresh variables. However, I am unsure about how to change my code to *accept* these non-fresh values, while type-checking against the fresh strings as shown with the first two calls.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhB2BzYALA8gMwMrAE4EskAeAFSggA9gEATAZyjr0MQBpZyraGBDeEANoBdKAF4owgHxioAKChQylavHpQABgBIA3kwJIAvjsIYIuKACUD6uQoUB%20WAmTpszYhfYCAdL5js9FiFJeTsALlgBACIAG2dUKKFZWVBIKBx9REw4JFRSThU1QKR2ADkC7ih4AFcAWwAjM2lxHJdMDJZSaWVK8scyCPgIADczZIxq%20ABjYHwAe3gofDoOpGz4lHye1QZitihy7bUahqaACj0IknY4%20AjSgEoIvSWGVayMVrzrg%20ltUNwEGA1Vwiz03luLjEonEt1kBnGkxm80WwB4AGsIO8tlwdox3IhJBc8BF3utcpsfgBWSQPKD-BT4DBQM4AQmWZM%20G1I7BpxNwvIedNQuDmAHcoABRXCi3BnKLvKCQ1BQVkwqBUqIPUJTBZ0OZxCFzRD87UI2QAegtUAA6nNcOi6KyWRhAXQUNq0Zj3vKAEz%20-1a5JWqAAQQYlEgMwgNHYZllDDOrog7s9GKxBL9AaDsjiwHx5nEUQDgeD1ulCagAFoq1AUOKoFM%20FAAJJQHjDOb4GhQVDLRz817wADk%20eTqZS6Z9egeQA)

Comment: Is the goal here that there is *no error* when passing a `string` type? Or should something else happen?

Comment: Thinking about it further -- that is essentially the boiled-down goal, since if it isn't fresh it immediately turns into a `string` type which then I can give *runtime* errors for instead of compile-time. (Basically a nudge to use a string of a certain length *if* it's directly passed in -- if its something like server input, it'll check during runtime.) **However**, wouldn't it be bad if it did that, and having a type guard be better for error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to accept

- valid literal string types
- just the `string` type

but don't want to accept

- invalid literal string types

we can add an additional check to the function parameter.

```
function takeString<
  T extends string
>(str: string extends T ? T : StringOfLength<T, 5>) {
  if (!isStringOfLength<T, 5>(str, 5)) throw Error("String length !== 5")
  console.log(str)
}
```

We accept `T` as an argument to the function if `string` extends `T`. But if `T` is a string literal, the argument's type must be `StringOfLength<T, 5>`. This might seem counter-intuitive as we check if `string extends T` before we even infer `T` but the compiler makes it work for us.

```
// Works! (fresh)
takeString("22222")

// As expected, errors (fresh)
takeString("2222")

let str = "22222"
// Does not error anymore
takeString(str)
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let str = "22222" as const` to tell TS that str will be the constant string `22222`. But I don't think it'll be terribly useful.

What you need here is to let TS know that `str` is a string of length 5. You can use this, but now you have redundant checks, just keep that in mind. `str is StringOfLength<T, N>` in the function's return type is the important part here.

```
let str = "22222" 

if (isStringOfLength(str, 5))
takeString(str)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhB2BzYALA8gMwMrAE4EskAeAFSggA9gEATAZyjr0MQBpZyraGBDeEANoBdKAF4owgHxioAKChQylavHpQABgBIA3kwJIAvjsIYIuKACUD6uQoUB+WAmTpszYhfYCAdL5js9FiFJeTsALlgBACIAG2dUKKFZWVBIKBx9REw4JFRSThU1QKR2ADkC7ih4AFcAWwAjM2lxHJdMDJZSaWVK8scyCPgIADczZIxq+ABjYHwAe3gofDoOpGz4lHye1QZitihy7bUahqaACj0IknY4+AjSgEoIvSWGVayMVrzrg+ltUNwEGA1Vwiz03luLjEonEt1kBnGkxm80WwB4AGsIO8tlwdox3IhJBc8BF3utcpsfgBWSQPKD-BT4DBQM4AQmWZM+G1I7BpxNwvIedNQuDmAHcoABRXCi3BnKLvKCQ1BQVkwqBUqIPUJTBZ0OZxCFzRD87UI2QAegtUAA6nNcOi6KyWRhAXQUNq0Zj3vKAEz+-1a5JWqAAQQYlEgMwgNHYZllDDOrog7s9GKxBL9AaDsjiwHx5nEUQDgbksiZLI5BPJLn5grT3szegeQA)

Comment: Hmm, so I should move my type check to the [actual variable declaration as so](https://tsplay.dev/NB50pw)?

Comment: This is is not useful `StringOfLength<string, 5>` will be `never`, not a `string`. You loose type information

Comment: @LeoDog896 I guess that would work without the redundant check